# Ts! It's itsy-bitsy limericks time!

Tags: pattern, limerick

(1)

> Once I and one more sneaky ass 
>  Planned heist of a hideous mass. 
>  - Let's steal all the (^-^)! 
>  - Man, hold up your (^-^). 
>  - (^-^). Then, let's steal all the grass!

(2)

> - My man, you look boring and (^-^), 
>  You have no chance of getting laid! 
>  - Then help me! - he (^-^). 
>  His (^-^) was an (^-^) 
>  Of school where he learned to look great.

(3)

> There once lived a negotiator, 
>  That had a response to each hater: 
>  - You ain't passed a (^-^) 
>  Of becoming a (^-^), 
>  Go (^-^) and I'll talk to you later.

(4)

> An ice-cream merchant from Westbridge 
>  Wants to exploit a Matrix glitch: 
>  - If I could (^-^) 
>  A single (^-^) 
>  That kind of (^-^) would make me rich!

(5)

> Right on the top (^-^) of little book (^-^) 
>  I found an old story, which pages I (^-^): 
>  The story was sad, 
>  It's driven me mad, 
>  A tale of a dwarf with no (^-^).

(6)

> Once Gandalf's life wasn't so merry, 
>  But now (^-^) man wants to marry! 
>  I hope you can (^-^) 
>  Him one certain (^-^) - 
>  He'll (^-^) it for his wife to carry.

(7)

> A joker found (^-^) at the peak, 
>  The jokes he made (^-^) of were weak. 
>  Devoted to (^-^), 
>  He aimed to (^-^), 
>  But none of the puns did the trick!

Comment: Though the limericks have a common theme, they do not 'synergise' - all you have to do is complete them separately.

Comment: Also, please copy the whole verse if answering. That will make the answer more readable.

Comment: Do all of the (^-^) rhyme, or just the words at the end of the lines?

Comment: @El-Guest Not all of them rhyme, but a bit more than only the end of the lines. That's a natural consequence of the secret pattern.

Comment: Wait, so the rhyme pattern of limerick #2 is going to be "AAAAA" instead of the classical "AABBA"?

Comment: @LinuxBlanket No, not really.

Comment: For (7), is the third line supposed to end in a comma? No matter how much I try, I can't seem to think of any way to grammatically complete the third line if it doesn't end in one.

Comment: @1848 it could be a typo. :D

Comment: There once was a user named Thomas / Whose lim'rcks were quite far from flawless / With so many words gone / His best bet was a con / To finish his poems he called us!

Comment: There once was a chap called @Reibello,/ 
Really quite an extraordinary fellow./
He paused to take time/
To construct comments in rhyme./
Ah, but if only Thomas was Yellow

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The pattern is

> each answer gains/losses one letter.

1.

> Once I and one more sneaky ass
>  Planned heist of a hideous mass.
>  - Let's steal all the **reed**!
>  - Man, hold up your **greed**.
>  - **Agreed**. Then, let's steal all the grass!

the pattern:

> **reed** > **greed** > **agreed**

2.

> My man, you look boring and **staid**,
>  You have no chance of getting laid!
>  Then help me! - he **said**.
>  His **aid** was an **ad**
>  Of school where he learned to look great.

the pattern:

> **staid** > **said** > **aid** > **ad**

3.

> There once lived a negotiator,
>  That had a response to each hater:
>  - You ain't passed a **clout**
>  Of becoming a **lout**,
>  Go **out** and I'll talk to you later.

the pattern:

> **clout** > **lout** > **out**

4.

> An ice-cream merchant from Westbridge
>  Wants to exploit a Matrix glitch:
>  - If I could **clone**
>  A single **cone**
>  That kind of **con** would make me rich!

the pattern:

> **clone** > **cone** > **con**

5.

> Right on the top **storey** of little book **store**
>  I found an old story, which pages I **tore**:
>  The story was sad,
>  It's driven me mad,
>  A tale of a dwarf with no **ore**.

the pattern:

> **storey** > **store** > **tore** > **ore**

6.

> Once Gandalf's life wasn't so merry,
>  But now **boring** man wants to marry!
>  I hope you can **bring**
>  Him one certain **ring** -
>  He'll **rig** it for his wife to carry.

the pattern:

> **boring** > **bring** > **ring** > **rig**

7.

> A joker found **us** at the peak,
>  The jokes he made **use** of were weak.
>  Devoted to **muse**,
>  He aimed to **amuse**,
>  But none of the puns did the trick!

the pattern:

> **us** > **use** > **muse** > **amuse**

the title:

> ts > its > itsy > bitsy (thanks @El-Guest!)

Comment: Forgive my forgetfulness. The 1 and 7 use the opposite pattern. That's the only reason that you couldn't find them.

Comment: Also, solution of (3) is far from the one I had in mind. Might I say, the second word there means a good thing, not an insult. However, I'll accept it as is.

Comment: @ThomasBlue That confirms my doubt as I have to extend quite the glossary for the (3). I hate to admit that right now I’m stumped. The only thing I got is a guess to (7) and it’s flimsy at best. ROT13(hf > hfr > zhfr > nzhfr) Also, is this what you meant by ‘the opposite pattern’; (yrff gb zber vafgrnq bs zber gb yrff?)

Comment: My apologies, I'm not a native speaker so I'm not too good with words. (7) is exactly the one you suggested (problem with ROT13(zhfr), I suppose? I wanted it to be a noun, like, a woman). "ad" is my try on singular form of "ads" I heard.

Comment: @ThomasBlue No.. no, the muse part is fine but because your limericks and their solutions are so good, It makes me doubt my own strength in every guess. So when you take that insecurity from my part away, your solution is just as perfect as any others. Really, it’s just a phrase that stems from my own insecurity when I’m wild guessing something and it has nothing to do with you. I’m the one who has to apologise for my careless remark.

Comment: @ThomasBlue Is (1) (errq > terrq > nterrq)? Ok, I think I'm gonna edit now. Please, let me know if this is enough to be accepted.

Comment: @Kevorobin, for the title you can go further to say r13(gf > vgf > vgfl > ovgfl)! Great finds for the limericks! :)

Comment: @El-Guest Nice! :)

Comment: @Kevorobin It's all correct! For anyone searching for better answers, I can say that (3) was originally made for words r13(fgntr > fntr > ntr).

Answer (score 6):

Limerick 4:

> An ice-cream merchant from Westbridge
>  Wants to exploit a Matrix glitch:
>  If I could but clone
>  A single small cone
>  That kind of scoop would make me rich!

Answer (score 4):

Partial:
(1)

> Once I and one more sneaky ass
>  Planned heist of a hideous mass.
>  Let's steal all the race courses!
>  Man, hold up your horses.
>  Curse this! Then, let's steal all the grass!

(2)

> There once lived a negotiator,
>  That had a response to each hater:
>   You ain't passed a test
>  Of becoming a pest,
>  Go rest and I'll talk to you later.

Comment: Both are wrong, though the second one sounds even better than the correct answer. I might reveal the correct pattern after a couple of days; or you will put your finger on it having solved more.

Answer (score 4):

A guess for #1 (not sure on the second word):

> Once I and one more sneaky ass
> Planned heist of a hideous mass.
> - Let's steal all the **HAY**!
> - Man, hold up your **PLAY**.
> - **OKAY**. Then, let's steal all the grass!
>
> Alternatives I considered for PLAY include DAY, WAY, SLEIGH

Answer (score 2):

(6)

> Once Gandalf's life wasn't so merry,
>  But now (the old) man wants to marry!
>  I hope you can (bring)
>  Him one certain (ring)
>  He'll (need?) it for his wife to carry.

(7)

> A joker found (out) at the peak,
>  The jokes he made (use) of were weak.
>  Devoted to (money)
>  He aimed to (be funny),
>  But none of the puns did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

3.

> There once lived a negotiator,
> That had a response to each hater:
> - You ain't passed a test
> Of becoming a best,
> Go west and I'll talk to you later.

Comment: I can put up with the fact that you didn't look for pattern. But you could at least try to make it rhyme! xD Anyways, still thanks for the input.

Comment: @ThomasBlue I fixed it.

Comment: @hakaboki No, not really. 'hater' would have to rhyme with 'test' which it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer, I'll try to solve as time permits.

**#2**:

> My man, you look boring and **plain** (could also be **restrained**, though this doesn't meet a traditional flow in syllables),
>  You have no chance of getting laid!
>  Then help me! - he **exclaimed**.
>  His (^-^) was an (^-^)
>  Of school where he learned to look great.

Comment: I fancy 'staid' for this one

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with limericks, so it would be great if someone could tell me if I'm doing something obviously wrong.

My attempts:
(7)

> A joker found (out) at the peak,
>  The jokes he made (fun) of were weak.
>  Devoted to (humor),
>  He aimed to (deliver),
>  But none of the puns did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Partial
For #1

> Once I and one more sneaky ass
>  Planned heist of a hideous mass.
>  Let's steal all the **gold**!
>  Man, hold up your **roll**.
>  **Cold**. Then, let's steal all the grass!

For #7

> A joker found **rest** at the peak,
>  The jokes he made **jest** of were weak.
>  Devoted to **ease** . 
>  He aimed to **please**,
>  But none of the puns did the trick!